# Disable JavaScript deleting HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, browser

Say I have a webpage which reacts to scrolling downwards by doing two things:

1. It adds new HTML at the bottom of the page;
2. It removes old HTML at the top of the page;

This is quite common in applications with an infinitely scrolling feed, like Twitter: it will only keep a fixed amount of tweets in the DOM.

Assuming I have access to the browser's JavaScript console, how could I disable part 2 of the above description? My very limited JavaScript experience tells me that running `Element.remove = () => { console.log("Nope!"); }` would work (regardless of how many different scripts are loaded on the webpage), but it doesn't.

Comment: Deleting a script tag won't disable that code if it's already in memory and you haven't reloaded.

Comment: Do you mean
`Element.prototype.remove=function(){
console.log("Nope")
}`
?

Comment: @ChangAlex That seems to be the syntactically correct form of what I meant. Strangely, this doesn't prevent the Twitter feed (specifically) from removing `div`s while scrolling. Any other ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe they cloned the function or something etc.
But note that `element.outerHTML=""` can remove the element too.